# 101Hero 3D Printer - Printed object is tilted

Tags: print-quality, 3d-models, 3d-design, ultimaker-cura, 101-hero

I am facing a problem with my 3D print. Whenever I am printing any object, the print from the top is shifting to the right hand side - it is symmetric at the bottom but not at the top.

Checkout the photo below:

[image: 101hero print]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a couple of issues here,

First off your nozzle appears to be a bit hot for your filament (you can see this be the drooping and sagginess of the layers on the outer shell)

Second issue is it appears as though your belts are loose. You can tell if your belts are loose if your parts seem to be shifted in one way.

Third issue (maybe). You may want to try slowing down your nozzle speed slightly. The faster the extruder moves, the more inertia that is generated which in effect makes your belt act as a spring and will cause it to bounce along the axis while it's printing. Slowing it down will result in your belt acting more like a rigid member and help to clean up the outer layers of your print. Also, it's easier on your belts. The downside is that your parts will take a bit longer to print. In my experience, parts that look great but take a bit longer are well worth the wait.

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause here is a loose belt on the X or Y drive, leading to hysteresis and a shift in the perceived origin of the system.  Try tightening the belts and adding tensioners.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using cura 15.02.1, also download the configuration file from the 101hero website, and upload it to cura using the" open profile" button. Make sure your extruder temp is set to 198. I use a 113% flow rate on my 101hero.